# URL of Meta Stack Exchange chat room transcript (which I opened from inbox) contains 2 slashes after "chat.meta.stackexchange.com". Why?

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, notifications, global-inbox, chat-transcript

I was chatting in a chat room and I went offline after some time. When I came back online, I checked my inbox and there was a chat reply in the chat room.

The URL of the transcript (which I opened from inbox) had two slashes after "chat.meta.stackexchange.com". Like this:

https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com//transcript/message/8583614#8583614

[image: Screenshot of notification of chat reply in inbox and the hyperlink]

Even if I remove one of the slashes, it's still the same website.

So what's the need of two slashes when we can use one? Is this a bug?

Comment: This is related: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8354/what-does-the-double-slash-mean-in-urls Seems like it was just a mistake.

Comment: Related, on MSO: [Double slash gets added to the URL when clicking on chat navigation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403111/4642212).

Answer (score 3):

It's not a bug, no.  The double forward slashes are an error in the programmer's/developer's code, like broken HTML.  A double forward slash in the URL is valid and will respond in the browser, but:

> If search engine crawlers find themselves crawling pages with double slashes, this could cause duplicate content issues and wasted crawl budget.

<sup>(That was quoted from [here](https://sitebulb.com/hints/internal/url-contains-a-double-slash/)).</sup>