# Extra slash added to the chat room URLs in the side bar

Tags: support, chat, hyperlinks, sidebar

There is a extra slash added to the chat room URLs in the side bar. This is not causing any redirection issue or 404 not found error.

Just observed it and want to notify to the development team about this. Seems it is not a bug, but that can [be corrected](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/8356).

Currently the following URLs are binded against the chat rooms in the side bar.

- Tavern on the Meta `https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com//rooms/89`
- The Fire Department `https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com//rooms/1181`

GIF for the reference:

[image: Extra slash in the chat URL]

Comment: Related, almost certainly duplicate: [URL of Meta Stack Exchange chat room transcript (which I opened from inbox) contains 2 slashes after "chat.meta.stackexchange.com". Why?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355147/289905).

Comment: Interesting.  Didn't simply vote @user289905's comment up...but yeah, it's a duplicate.  I answered that question and also linked to a document that explains it more thouroughly.